# asp.net c# display data in label - System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to pull a value from SQL into a label in ASP.Net using C# but it is just dispaying System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label. 
I've run in debug and I can see the C# is pulling back the value I expect, how do I get this to display in the ASP?

C# Code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SEV2"].ConnectionString;
string commandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS TotalApplicants FROM (SELECT tbl_Candidate.CandID, tbl_Candidate.FirstName, tbl_Candidate.LastName FROM tbl_Candidate INNER JOIN tbl_CandProfile ON tbl_Candidate.CandID = tbl_CandProfile.CandID) a";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    lblTotalApplicants = reader["TotalApplicants"].ToString();
}
this.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

ASP.Net Code:

```
<div class="stat-content dib">
    <div class="stat-text">Total Applicants</div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalApplicants" class="stat-digit" runat="server" Text="">
        <%# lblTotalApplicants %>
    </asp:Label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns an integer value, so you want to use `ExecuteScalar`.

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string connectionString = 
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SEV2"].ConnectionString;
    string commandText = "YOUR QUERY";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        lblTotalApplicants.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

### ASPX

Remove `<%# lblTotalApplicants %>`

```
<div class="stat-content dib">
    <div class="stat-text">Total Applicants</div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalApplicants" class="stat-digit" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind the content inside the `Label` control. You should use the `Text` property. This should do the job:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalApplicants" Text="<%# totalApplicants %>" class="stat-digit" runat="server">
```

Remember that `totalApplicants` should be a `protected` variable on your page.

You could also just set the `Text` property server-side:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    lblTotalApplicants.Text = reader["TotalApplicants"].ToString();
}
```